# При попытке посчитать количество оставшихся дней, в DBMS_OUTPUT дни отображаются с минусом

Tags: логика

Друзья.

У меня такая задача:
Получить по ID клиента информацию о его открытом вкладе.
Необходимо отобразить номер договора вклада, и дату с которой он действует.
А также сколько дней осталось до его закрытия, относительно текущей дате, в случае если договор открыт.
Если вклад клиента уже закрыт, то отобразить соответствующее сообщение.

**Незнаю почему, но в Output-е у меня отображается количество дней с минусом.**

**Должно быть так: 65**

**А сейчас отображается так: -65**

Таблица вкладов (Deposits):
[image: Смотрим только тот вклад который с ClientID - 103. Отредактировал дату начала действия, чтобы удобно было работать с текущим днем/месяцем. Т.к. другие уже теоритически закрыты (открыты год назад)]

Вот что я успел написать, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

*Используемая версия Oracle: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0*

```
DECLARE
vClientID         NUMBER;
vDepStartDate     DATE;
vDepEndDate       NUMBER;
vDepDays          NUMBER;
vDogNum           VARCHAR2(10);
vCountMoreOneDep  NUMBER;
vDateClose        DATE;
BEGIN
  vClientID := 103;
  
SELECT DOG_NUM, DOG_DATE
  INTO vDogNum, vDepStartDate
  FROM Deposits
 WHERE ClientID = vClientID;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Договор № ' || vDogNum || ', '|| 'действует с ' || to_char(vDepStartDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));


SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-DOG_DATE-DEPOSITDAYS
  INTO vDepEndDate
  FROM DEPOSITS
 WHERE ClientID = vClientID;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('До закрытия вклада осталось: ' || vDepEndDate);

SELECT COUNT(DOG_NUM)
  INTO vCountMoreOneDep
  FROM DEPOSITS
 WHERE ClientID = vClientID
   AND DEPOSIT_STATUS = 1;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Извините, данный запрос не может быть обработан, т.к. у клиента несколько вкладов.');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Пожалуйста, обратитесь к менеджеру для уточнения информации.');
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('По клиенту: ' || (vClientID) || (' вклады не найдены.')); 
END;
```

Comment: Если в результате будет отрицательное число, то оно будет выведено с минусом. Почему вас это удивляет?

Comment: А если из меньшего вычитать большее - так результат и будет отрицательным.

Comment: @Akina - друзья, я прекрасно понимаю это. Но, как мне получить тот же результат, без минуса ?

Comment: Можно получить с abs(resultat), но он будет возможно неверный.

Comment: *как мне получить тот же результат, без минуса ?* Да тупо поменять местами уменьшаемое и вычитаемое... ну чё ты, в самом-то деле...

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо за участие в вопросе.

Надо было к дате договора, прибавить количество дней на который клиент открыл вклад и высчитать из него текущую дату (SYSDATE).

А у меня было так:
Я высчитывал из SYSDATE, дату открытия и дату на который размещен вклад. В итоге я получал -65 дней, т.е. по факту у меня вклад закончился 65 дней назад. Мое суждение что нужно просто убрать минус, и оставить 65 дней было неверным.

Было так:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-DOG_DATE-DEPOSITDAYS
  INTO vDepEndDate
  FROM DEPOSITS
 WHERE ClientID = vClientID;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('До закрытия вклада осталось: ' || vDepEndDate);
```

Нужно так:

```
SELECT DOG_DATE+DEPOSITDAYS-TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  INTO vDepEndDate
  FROM DEPOSITS
 WHERE ClientID = vClientID;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('До закрытия вклада осталось: ' || vDepEndDate);
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, какое отношение имеют метки под вопросом к теме вопроса? Ведь вы просто в бизнес логике запутались.